# Recovering replaced Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to recover a Jupyter Notebook that i replaced by mistake on Ubuntu. Is there a way to get that?

lets say I had A.ipynb but by mistake i replaced that with another A.ipynb and now i am trying to get the 1st A.ipynb

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only way to get it back is if you have a backup of the first version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: I tried the grep method thats mentioned there but it doesnt return the notebook i want. Technically that thread is about delete, so i am not sure how it works if i replaced a file.